# For multiple mysql instance , fresh download required when one exist?

Tags: windows, mysql-5.6

i need multiple instances of Mysql on same server.
I had been through many links , but i confused here :

```
What i have : MySQL 5.6 is already installed on my windows server A.
Installed at : "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL_Server_5.6\"

Problem :   For multiple instances , do i need to download and install new mysql(either same or higher version) on server A ?

OR
  should i just copy existing my.conf file in new folder and then change its port number and then done.
```

My own analysis goes on fresh installation , but please confirm .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did is :

```
       i used existing my.cnf file and copy it in another location and edit
       some part of it :

         1. Commented #port=3306
         2. Added these lines at the end.
           [mysqld1]
           basedir ="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"
           port = 3307
           enable-named-pipe
           socket = mypipe1

           [mysqld2] 
           basedir ="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"
           port = 3308
           enable-named-pipe
           socket = mypipe2
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this simple steps , It will easier to do multiple instances on same server
http://bingobo.info/blog/recipes/how-to-set-up-separate-mysql-instance-on-windows.jsp